# Use SVG file as React component

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have code like this:

`<img src={category.svg} alt={category.name} />`

It works, but as image not React component and I cannot any manipulation. SVG URL is changing dynamically and I cannot import or convert it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Don't use an <img> if you want it to be interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom react Component `Svg` like this

```
import { memo } from "react";
import inlinesvg from "react-inlinesvg";

const Svg = memo(inlinesvg);

export default Svg;
```

And now whenever you need to use this component, with a specific `.svg` file, use it like this:

```
import One from "resources/images/one.svg";
import Two from "resources/images/two.svg";
...
...

return  <Svg src={this.props.isOne ? One : Two}/>
```

Comment: Is it possible don't use import? SVG path comes from database.

Comment: The `src`  contains the  SVG file you want to load. It can be a require, URL or a string (base64 or url encoded). More details here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inlinesvg